# Run Stored Procedure with table data as parameter

Tags: c#, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have number of ids in id_table and I need to run this procedure for at least how many rows in table1.  I am using while loop to run loop till counts finish in table1 but can anyone tell me how can I change @ID every time.

If anyone can tell me how to do in c# will also be fine.

```
declare @ID INT
declare @noRun1 INT
declare @howTime INT

set @noRun1=1
set @howTime = (select count(*) from table1)
set @ID =(select top 1 id from id_table)

while (@noRun1<=@howTime)
begin 
    EXEC proc_run @ID
set @noRun1=@noRun1+1
end
```

Comment: What version of SQL-Server are you using? Could [TABLE-VALUED PARAMETERS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489%28SQL.100%29.aspx) be an option?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
    DECLARE @uniqueId int
DECLARE @TEMP TABLE (uniqueId int)
-- Insert into the temporary table a list of the records to be updated
INSERT INTO @TEMP (uniqueId) SELECT uniqueId FROM myTable

-- Start looping through the records
WHILE EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @TEMP)
BEGIN
-- Grab the first record out
SELECT Top 1 @uniqueId = uniqueId FROM @TEMP
PRINT 'Working on @uniqueId = ' + CAST(@uniqueId as varchar(100))
-- Perform some update on the record
EXEC proc_run @uniqueId
-- Drop the record so we can move onto the next one
DELETE FROM @TEMP WHERE uniqueId = @uniqueId
END
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to execute a stored procedure for each id in your table?
Rewrite your selection of id so that you can skip a number of rows. Something like this:

```
while (@noRun1 <= @howTime)
begin 
    select @ID = id from
        (select id, (ROW_NUMBER() over (order by id)) as numrow from id_table) as tab
    where numrow = @noRun1

    EXEC proc_run @ID

    set @noRun1 = @noRun1 + 1
end
```

If you are using SQL Server 2008+ you can rewrite your stored procedure to accept table-valued parameters, pass the whole list of ids and only execute once. Check out this example: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb510489.aspx