# Ignore column for one iteration of a looped parameterized update statement

Tags: sql, t-sql

If I have a parameterized update statement in a loop, [as explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19268588/sql-query-execution-inside-a-for-loop)...

```
SqlCommand cmd4 = new SqlCommand("update TrackingFaculty_det " + 
                                "SET Name=@Name, EmailsentDate=@Email WHERE FID=@FID", cn1);
cn1.Open();
cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Email", SqlDbType.DateTime, 8);
cmd4.Parameters.Add("@FID",SqlDbType.VarChar,10);
cmd4.Parameters.Add("@Name",SqlDbType.VarChar,50);
for (int i = 0; i <= GridView1.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
{
   .....
   if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
   {
      ....
      cmd4.Parameters["@Email"].Value = sdt;
      cmd4.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID1;
      cmd4.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
      cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
   }
}
cn1.Close();
```

...is there a magic value I can put in the parameter for a given iteration to **not update**, to keep the column's existing value?

Comment: What about adding the check for specific iteration number to that if condition?

Answer (score 1):

For example if you don't want to update the row when `i == 4`, you can check it in the `if` statement:

```
if (Ckbox.Checked == true)
{
    ....
    if (i == 4)
        cmd4.Parameters["@Email"].Value = sdt;
    else
        cmd4.Parameters["@Name"].Value = Name;
    cmd4.Parameters["@FID"].Value = FID1;
    cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

Comment: sorry there was a vital line missing inside my for loop. If I want to update say EmailsentDate but not Name, can I do that?

Comment: @user1585345 I updated my answer. You can check if `i == 4` and then set the value you want to pass to `cmd4`.

Comment: yup, but the parameter keeps it's value from the previous iteration of the loop.

Comment: You could set `cmd4.Parameters["@Email"].Value` to `null` after `cmd4.ExecuteNonQuery()` or call `cmd4.Parameters.Clear()`. But in the second case you have to set all parameters again in the next turn of the loop.